# Android Studio Sidebars Gone and Not Pinning Correctly

Tags: android-studio

This may be a very simple fix but it took me forever to find out where I had accidentally clicked.

I was having having issues where android studio was not correctly pinning or grouping windows; see my solution below..

Answer (score 0):

Check the bottom left of Android Studio for this icon:

[image]

If you do not see this icon, press the icon until it shows. This puts android studio into a 'focus' mode of some sort.

Hope this helps someone else, cheers!